# Automatically move a group of windows to another monitor in OSX

Tags: osx-snow-leopard, multiple-monitors, window-manager

I've searched around without much luck, and have a few ideas on how to do this one by one.  Here is the situation.  5 million windows opened up on my main screen.  I move chat, twitter, etc. to my laptop screen while I work.  When I disconnect my laptop, everything goes to the same screen, obviously. When I reconnect, I spend 20 minutes moving and realigning my windows.  The ideal solution would be able to hit a hot key and have everything magically move to a predefined place.

I've looked at SizeUp, but that seems to be a one by one solution.  Could you use automator + size up to make all of this happen at once?

Any ideas, help or links are greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Try [Stay](http://cordlessdog.com/stay/).

Comment: Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.